# Does exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|\theta_1 - \theta_2| \leq C|e^{i\theta_1}- e^{i\theta_2}|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Consider $S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb C: |z| = 1 \}$. Given $z_1 = e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_2 = e^{i\theta_2}$, we have that [$|e^{i\theta_1}- e^{i\theta_2}| \leq |\theta_1 - \theta_2|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924147/prove-that-ei-theta-1-ei-theta-2-leq-theta-1-theta-2).

I'm trying to see if exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$ |\theta_1 - \theta_2| \leq C|e^{i\theta_1}- e^{i\theta_2}|.$

Desenvolving $|e^{i\theta_1}- e^{i\theta_2}|$

$$|e^{i\theta_1}- e^{i\theta_2}|^2 = |(\cos \theta_1 - \cos \theta_2) + i(\sin \theta_1 - \sin \theta_2)|^2 = 2(1 - \sin{(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}).$$

How ever, I don't which constant work.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [C. Falcon pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2399492/42969),
such an estimate cannot exist.

Following [tristan's remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399491/does-exists-a-constant-c0-such-that-theta-1-theta-2-leq-cei-theta#comment4951361_2399492)
one can reduce the difference modulo 
$2 \pi$ such that
$$
 \theta_1 - \theta_2 = \delta + 2 \pi k \quad \text{with }|\delta| \le \pi ,
 k \in \Bbb Z \, .
$$
Then
$$
|e^{i\theta_1} - e^{i\theta_2}| = 2|\sin \frac{\theta_1 - \theta_2}2|
 = 2  |\sin \frac \delta 2| \ge \frac 2 \pi |\delta| 
$$
where the first identity is shown in 
[Prove that $|e^{i\theta_1}-e^{i\theta_2}| \leq |\theta_1 - \theta_2|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924147/prove-that-ei-theta-1-ei-theta-2-leq-theta-1-theta-2/924149#924149)
and the final estimate follows from [$1)$ For $ 0\le \theta \le\frac{\pi}{2}$, show that $\sin \theta \ge \frac{2}{\pi} \theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163175/1-for-0-le-theta-le-frac-pi2-show-that-sin-theta-ge-frac2-p).

If $\theta_1 - \theta_2 = \pi$ then equality holds, so the estimate
is best possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is **false.** Indeed, let $\theta_1=0$ and $\theta_2=2\pi$. The argument is not even a continuous function on $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: It depends on how you define the argument :) One could argue that the argument of a complex number belongs to $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @tristan Indeed, nice touch! :)