# How to evaluate the limit $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}Re^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta \quad (\text{as } R \rightarrow \infty)$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

While doing a mathematical exercise(stein Complex Analysis chapter2,exercise 3),
I managed to reduce the problem to the following one:

> $$\int_{0}^{\omega}Re^{-R\cos\theta}d\theta  \rightarrow 0  \quad  (\text{as } R \rightarrow \infty)$$  where $0\le \omega <\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I can prove this without much difficulty:
$$\int_{0}^{\omega}Re^{-R\cos\theta}d\theta \le \int_{0}^{\omega}Re^{-R\cos\omega}d\theta =\omega Re^{-R\cos\omega}  \rightarrow 0  \quad  (\text{as } R \rightarrow \infty)$$
It is crucial that $\omega $ is strictly less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This lead me to raise another interesting problem: what the limit will be if we replace $\omega$ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. After changing $\cos\theta$ to $\sin\theta$ (this doesn't matter), now my question is

## $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}Re^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta  \rightarrow ?  \quad  (\text{as } R \rightarrow \infty)$$

I have no idea how to calculate, I even don't know if the limit exists.

Comment: how are you evaluating the original integral?

Comment: You could try series expanding the exponential and integrating each term as a beta function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function or alternatively try the jacobi-anger expansion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion the result may well be a bessel function but I'm guessing without trying it

Comment: Would you please try that method, which i am not familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $I(R)$ your integral and $J(R)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}R\cos(\theta)^2\exp(-R\sin(\theta))d\theta$, $K(R)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}R\sin(\theta)^2\exp(-R\sin(\theta))d\theta$. We have $I(R)=J(R)+K(R)$;  Note that the function $u\exp(-u)$ is positive and bounded on $[0,+\infty[$, say by $M$.

a) For $K(R)$, we have $R\sin(\theta)^2\exp(-R\sin(\theta))\leq M$ for all $\theta$, and this function goes to $0$  everywhere if $R\to +\infty$. By the Dominated convergence theorem, $K(R)\to 0$ as $R\to +\infty$.

b) For $J(R)$, we integrate by parts:
$$J(R)=[(\cos(\theta)(-\exp(-R\sin(\theta))]_0^{\pi/2}-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)\exp(-R\sin(\theta))d\theta$$ 
 We have hence $J(R)=1-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)\exp(-R\sin(\theta))d\theta$. Now apply the dominated convergence theorem to $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)\exp(-R\sin(\theta))d\theta$, and you are done.

Comment: thank you for your answer. by dominated convergence theorem, you mean that in the real analysis ?can you provide more information about that theorem?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem.

Comment: i have learned that before. but i never know that  the theorem  can be applied in this situation.

Comment: For $K(R)$, we have $R\sin(\theta)^2\exp(-R\sin(\theta))\leq M$ for all $\theta$.    is there any problem here??

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Here the dominant function is the function equal to $M$ for all $\theta$.

Comment: what if when $\theta =0$

Comment: ?? $sin(0)=0$ What is your question ?

Comment: oh! I made a mistake just now. thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic integral in any textbook. $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}Re^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta\le\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}Re^{-R\frac{2\theta}{\pi}}d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\pi(1-e^{-R})\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2} \quad  (\text{as } R \rightarrow \infty).$$

Comment: Yes , but i want to know the exact value. Can you do that?

Comment: The trick is $\sin{\theta}\ge\frac{\theta}{\pi/2}$ over $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Can you prove that?

Answer (score 1):

$$I_R=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}R\,e^{-R\sin(\theta)}\,d\theta=\frac{\pi  R}{2}  \,(I_0(R)-\pmb{L}_0(R))$$ where appear Bessel and Struve functions.

The result tends (quite slowly) to $1$ when $R$ becomes larger and larger as shown in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
R & I_R \\
  10 & 1.01126 \\
 11 & 1.00909 \\
 12 & 1.00750 \\
 13 & 1.00630 \\
 14 & 1.00538 \\
 15 & 1.00465 \\
 16 & 1.00406 \\
 17 & 1.00358 \\
 18 & 1.00318 \\
 19 & 1.00284 \\
 20 & 1.00256
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you look [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Struve_function), at the bottom of the page, you will find the very interesting asymprotic relation
$$\pmb{L}_n(x)=I_{-n}(x)-\frac{x^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Use $n=0$ to get the value of $1$.

Comment: thanks for the data, which means the limit should be 1.can you prove this

Comment: @王李远. Have a look to my edit.

Comment: @王李远. USing the values $10 \leq R \leq 100$, a quick and dirty regression gives $\approx 1+\frac {1.41}{R^{2.10}}$ where the coefficients are highly significant.

Comment: that's great ! thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward application of [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). Since $\sin(\theta)$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$ we have that the main contribution of the integral comes from near $\theta$ around zero. So by applying Laplace's method, we get:
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 e^{-R \sin\theta}\,d\theta = \frac{1}{R} + o\left( \frac 1 R\right)
\end{align}
as $R\to\infty$ and therefore:
\begin{align} 
\lim_{R\to\infty} \int^{\pi/2}_0 Re^{-R \sin\theta}\,d\theta = 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Put
\begin{equation*}
I(R)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}Re^{-R\sin \theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta= \int_{0}^{\pi/4}Re^{-R\sin \theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}Re^{-R\sin \theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta .
\end{equation*}
Integration by parts yields
\begin{gather*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}Re^{-R\sin \theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta = \left[\dfrac{-1}{\cos\theta}e^{-R\sin \theta}\right]_{0}^{\pi/4}+ \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2\theta}e^{-R\sin \theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta=1-\sqrt{2}e^{-R/\sqrt{2}}+\\[2ex]\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2\theta}e^{-R\sin \theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta .
\end{gather*}
But according to Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2\theta}e^{-R\sin \theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta \to 0, \quad R\to\infty
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}Re^{-R\sin \theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta \to 0, \quad R\to\infty.
\end{equation*}
Consequently
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{R\to\infty}I(R)=1.
\end{equation*}

Comment: That's a great method! thanks！

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(R)=\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R\cos\theta}\mathbb d\theta$.
Note that
\begin{align*}
F(R)
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta e^{-R\cos\theta}\mathbb d\theta+G(R)\\
&=\frac{1-e^{-R}}{R}+G(R),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
0\leq G(R)
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\sin\theta)e^{-R\cos\theta}\mathbb d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\cos\theta)e^{-R\sin\theta}\mathbb d\theta\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(\theta/2)e^{-R\sin\theta}\mathbb d\theta\\
&\leq\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\theta^2e^{-2R\theta/\pi}\mathbb d\theta\\
&\leq\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\theta^2e^{-2R\theta/\pi}\mathbb d\theta\\
&=\frac{\pi^3}{8R^3}
\end{align*}
This proves that, for large $\beta$ we have
$$F(R)=\frac{1}{R}+O\left(\frac{1}{R^3}\right),\quad R\to\infty.$$
So
$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int^{\pi/2}_0 Re^{-R \sin\theta}\mathbb d\theta=1.$$